# How can I call non-static value in ascx file? (.net framework 1.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I got a class like this:

```
namespace MYSCommon
{
   [Serializable]
   public class Cart
   {        

    // Methods
    public Cart(){
         //Code skip
    }

    public double Value{
        //Code skip
    }
   }
}
```

I use this method to call in the aspx, it got an error:

The code:
`<%= MYSCommon.Cart.Value %>`

The error:
`Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'MYSCommon.Cart.Value'`

But I got another like this:

```
namespace MYSCommon
{
    public class Constant
    {
        // Fields
        public static string staticValue = "Something";
    }
}
```

and called it via: `<%= MYSCommon.Constant.staticValue %>`, which is success. 
How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access instance variable without the class instance. In the code behind of `ascx` you may create a public instance of type `Cart` like:

Code behind of ascx:

```
public MYSCommon.Cart myCart = new MYSCommon.Cart();
```

later you can access it like:

in `ascx`:

```
<span> <%= myCart.Value %> </span>
```

*Just make sure that `myCart` is declared as `public` and at `Page` level.*

Comment: I am not able to get back the Code behind of ascx, is there any workaround?